# Invoking C++ code from Java (GCJ)

Tags: java, c++, g++, gcj, cross-language

I'm trying to invoke C++ from Java using GCJ using the CNI, so far I'm able to invoke Java code from C++. How can I invoke C++ from Java using the CNI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll extend somewhat on pcent's answer to read the [GCJ/CNI Docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcj/About-CNI.html).

I believe that the key is to understand the whole "CNI C++ class" concept.

- The creation of a CNI C++ class is explained in [that page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcj/Basic-concepts.html).
- You can call Java code from a CNI C++ class (provided you have generated header files) - that's what you already do (calling Java from C++).
- The key point is that *CNI C++ methods can be invoked from Java* (because these classes have a set of restrictions upon them to make them Java-compatible). And because the CNI class is only a (particular kind of) C++ class, you can also link it to other libraries just as you would link any C++ class.

Most of the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcj/About-CNI.html) describes how the Java conventions translate in a CNI C++ class.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading [GCJ/CNI Docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcj/About-CNI.html)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not a good Java-programmer, but I'm familar with C#/C++ interop. The best solution for me to call from native C++ to managed C# was using **Callbacks**. I think this applies also to **JNI**

Try reading: http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/07/java-native-interface-jni-example-using.html

Comment: The question wasn't about JNI -- it was about CNI, which is a different beast entirely.